# Standard Private/Public Properties Adoption ECMAScript and Lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

If, or when Salesforce decides to adopt a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) for both public and private field declarations.

Would the [@api decorator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators) become obsolete? meaning that all non "hashed" properties/methods would remain private to the class, and "non-hashed" properties/methods public and "exposable".

Today, any public property or method must be `@api` decorated to be exposed, however, when the aforementioned proposal becomes a standard, Javascript would allow support private properties and methods as follows:

```
class ClassWithPrivateField {
  #privateField
}

class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world'
  }
}
```

and public properties would basically be what we know as private properties in an LWC component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    
    myPrivateProperty;
}
```

This might be a bit confusing and seems counterintuitive, but, I'm curious to know what Salesforce will do once this proposal becomes a standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a great question! It's something that we discussed in the past among LWC team members. We don't have a concrete plan yet on how would private fields and methods would play with LWC components.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2335) on Github to discuss this openly. Feel free to follow/comment if you are interested.